# Eigenvector and eigenvalue with cvBlobsLib

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I use [cvBlobsLib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib) for blob detection. At the moment I need large and small eigenvalue and corresponding eingenvectors. All what I could find in the documentation of library is `CBlobGetMajorAxisLength` and `CBlobGetMinorAxisLength`. If I am right: first gives me the large eigenvalue and the second - the small eigenvalue. But now I also need eigenvectors which I could not find in the library.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a way to get the orientation angle of the blob.  Rooting through the documentation (downloaded [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=cvblobslib_OpenCV_v8_3.zip), which is not in English, but can be understood) I found:

> CBlobGetOrientation Class Reference
>
> Public Member Functions

```
double  operator() (const CBlob &blob) const
```

> Aplica l'operació al blob.

```
const char *    GetNom () const
```

> Obté el nom de l'operador.

So, if you have the magnitude of the axis and it's orientation, you should be able to derive everything else.  The only trick is, I'm not sure what the angle is referenced to.

Comment: Thank you! I found that the angle is between the horiz. axis and length of the blob.